# No pipe symbol in Ubuntu 11.04 running in Windows 7 x64 VirtualBox

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, keyboard-layout

For some reason I cannot type a pipe(|) symbol with US keyboard in Ubuntu while I can do it in Windows 7 which also uses US keyboard. Normally I use left-shift with the button next to it to type a pipe symbol, but in Ubuntu it creates < and > with shift (like "shift+," and "shift+." are already doing).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I fixed this for my Dell keyboard by running

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

and selecting the most similar keyboard (SK-7100, I think - my actual keyboard is a SK-8165) and guessing sensible options for the other questions (in my case, UK layout, extended-winkeys, no compose).

This was for Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS 64-bit on VMWare 4.04, host: Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: this one worked for me.

Comment: This also worked for me – slightly hard to believe that you still need to do this in Ubuntu in 2014! Thank you.

Comment: And you have to it after every kernel update

Comment: @AndrewFielden Thanks, that's a shame but useful to know! Might be possible to automate it - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8671308/non-interactive-method-for-dpkg-reconfigure

Comment: This also solved my problem of not being able to type ~ (tilde) and | (pipe) on a German keyboard in Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Thank you, that is super useful - my keyboard somehow got set to Romanian, so pipe and colon symbols didn't render correctly.  This fixed the problem!

Answer (score 4):

Try this

1. Hold down the <kbd>ALT</kbd> key
2. Enter <kbd>1</kbd>,<kbd>2</kbd>,<kbd>4</kbd> on the numeric keyboard (you might
   need to activate it via the <kbd>Num Lock</kbd>toggle key)
3. Release the <kbd>ALT</kbd> key

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

If you can’t type pipe (|) then change keyboard layout

command is : setxkbmap us

It's work for me

Answer (score 0):

try "shift" + "some key next to enter". I have on my us keyboard two pipe keys - one next to left shift and one right above the enter key.

Answer (score -1):

if you are using UK keyboard try 
Yaast -> System -> Language
Primary Language -> English UK
check adapt kyboard and timezone to UK .

This worked for me.